# HTML Font list dropdown

Tags: html, select, fonts, drop-down-menu

Is there a script or function I can call to create a font dropdown menu?  Of a lot of fonts?  so once selected it can be used in an from the database on to the website? (aka let the user select their font type):

More specifically the five or so standard "Web safe" fonts.

Or can someone just list those 5 fonts for when using them in html.

Ex:

```
<font face="????">Text</font>
```

Comment: Needs more info. Which fonts do you mean - those installed on the user's computer, or the five or so standard more or less "Web safe" fonts?

Comment: Edited to be a lil more specific, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You could do this entirely in css if you wish:

```
<select>
    <option class="font1"></option>
    <option class="font2"></option>
    <option class="font3"></option>
    <option class="font4"></option>
    <option class="font5"></option>
</select>

<style>
    .font1 {font-family:arial}
    .font2 {font-family:monospace}
    ... etc
</style>
```

Also I would avoid using the font tag, it's deprecated as of HTML4 I believe.
If you have a ridiculous amount of fonts I would automate the markup generation with PHP or another HTML geared language of your choice. If you need specifics on how to do this just let me know.